# Mac - Permission denied (publickey) - Cannot not read from remote repository

Tags: git, macos, github

I tried cloning my project from github. I am getting the following error in my mac during the cloning process.

```
Permission denied (publickey) fatal - Could not read from remote repository.
```

i have already added the ssh key to my github account .

Comment: i tried most of the solution given

but in rahul's answer step 7 i.e :-

ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 
fixed my issue